# Turn ON/OFF 5V 2-5A by Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi, high-current, 3.3v

I need to control few 5V 2-5A devices by rpi GPIOs, which has the 3.3V logic level. I come up with a simple circuit, but I'll appreciate any ideas, corrections, suggestions. The LOAD is something like a powerful LED flashlight (pure real load, without reactive elements). It won't turn on/off often (once in a few minutes), so it shouldn't be a big problem with frequencies. All LOADs have common ground wire: they are parts of one device and all connected to the ground wire and chassis.

Is the circuit correct? Is it possible to improve it? MOSFET is 100V, is there any better choice?

[image: ciruit]

**UPDATE**
After @brhans comment, I'm considering also Mosfet IRF9540 (it can work with 3A at 5V) or several FDN340P, but they are in SOT23 package (hard to assemble with my equipment). Is IRF9540 a better choice?

Comment: Do your loads _need_ common ground or just _use_ it. In the second case you might be able to go with low-side switches and reduce number of components.

Comment: Please ask a question so it can be answered, we don't do suggestions. Specific questions get good answers. This is a Q&A site, not a general fourm

Comment: @Maple They are physically wired, that is why I have to use P-MOSFET

Comment: That may not be the best choice of MOSFET to use with a 5V supply. it really wants >6V to turn on properly (7-8V would be better).

Comment: @brhans Thank you for the comment. Very useful. Can you suggest something better? I tried to find low-threshold p-MOSFET, but all of them SOIC. :(

Comment: @rth if you ever need to edit your questions, there is a button at the bottom of the post